# Getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` or `IllegalArgumentException` on `arraylist.get(something)` on probable rooted phones, android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I get crash reports from the play console saying either there has been a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` or `IllegalArgumentException` but the latter is less often. This happens when `arraylist.get(something)` is **executed**, where something is an *int* which is got by passing `size = arraylist.size();` to  `something = random.nextInt(size)` .

When the app is loaded it reads a bunch of data and populates the arraylist, after that mainActivity is started and so on.

Now I know what you're thinking, this must be a simple case of of getting the wrong size of the arraylist or something like that. But no, I've made sure to first check, if the size that is passed into `random.nextInt(size)` is greater than 0 and also I do this,

```
size = arraylist.size() - 3;
```

though there is no necessity to do that.
Moreover I know my array will have a **fixed size, 1010**. It is static. I load it once when the app is started and does not change after that.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2726)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2787)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1504)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6247)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:872)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:411)
  at myapp.app.Spelling.nextWord (Spelling.java:346)
  at myapp.app.Spelling.onCreate (Spelling.java:120)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6757)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2679)
```

-

```
size_of_wor = StartDisplay.wor.size() - 3;

public void nextWord() {
    display.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    submit.setText("OK");
    if (size_of_wor > 0)
        rend = random.nextInt(size_of_wor);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please restart app",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    givenWord = StartDisplay.wor.get(rend);// crashes here

    theWord = givenWord.getw();
    String placeholder = "hint : " + givenWord.getm();
    soundHint.setText(placeholder);
    spellSound();
}
```

But whatever I do i still get the crash report. So far I just have not been able to reproduce this crash on my device, I tried it on emulator using android K,M,L,N and still no crash.

I'm using android support version 23.3.1

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: ArrayLists don't have a fixed size, Arrays do.

Comment: Maybe what he's trying to say is that he creates the ArrayList statically with 1010 elements always and its not a dynamic one with variable length depending on the situation

Comment: @mmmcho, add the code which fails, otherwise it will be hard to help

Comment: ok I've added the crash and the code

Answer (score 2):

if `arraylist.size()` is `<= 3`, variable `size` will hold `0`

`var = random.nextInt(size)`  will throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`, since bounds *must be positive*

Comment: but my array is static and I know it will have a size of 1010 and won't change ever.